# Pagination in Big Commerce - Not Pre-Fixing correctly

Tags: pagination, bigcommerce

I'm using a stencil theme in Big Commerce and am having an issue with the pagination buttons. When I click on the page number or next button, the site prefix is not adding an additional `/` to the end of the url.

The url should read as follows:

```
https://example.com/learn-more/?page=2
```

but clicking the buttons only links back to the main blog page:

```
https://example.com/learn-more/
```

I went through the "Store Front > Blog > {...} (settings) > About This Blog" and made sure the blog url was set to the correct format ( i.e.- `/blog/` }, but that is not having the correct effect.

I'm gettting familiar with the stencil themes, but I'm lost on how to correct urls in this format, as the normal react fixes are not there...

**Please Help**

Comment: Hi @kieran, I just wanted to let you know that we're aware of this behavior and are working on it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Thomas and heather. Tom,bi spoke with the site owner and am working on getting access to edit the js pages, so I will attempt your fix and get back to you as soon as I can to let you know it worked. In the mean time, Heather can you mark this issue as answered for me? I'm afraid my stack rating is too low to like or upvote or anything... Thanks again, guys!!!

Comment: Hi @kieran, I do not believe that I can mark your question as resolved. But I upvoted the answer from Dave to show support of this solution. Thanks :)

Comment: also, this should be fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, same issue here. After playing with the blog settings like you did, I ended up applying a workaround by correcting the URLs via script just to fix it quickly.

```
    const isBlogPostsPage = $('.blogPosts').length > 0;
    if (isBlogPostsPage) {
        $('.pagination-link').each(function() {
            let link = $(this).attr('href');
            link = link.replace('/articles?', '/articles/?');
            $(this).attr('href', link);
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's smooth how you swapped it out with replace. Hats off to you and thanks for the assist:)

Comment: Thank, guys. That put me over the line and I can do stuff on so now. :)